# how to specifiy this url in django 127.0.0.1:8000/?uid=Mjg&token=5dj-ddf5e0d6cf0d6f03dfc1

Tags: django

Some URLs configured in my django project are like so:

```
path('<str:uid>/<str:token>/', views.activate,name="activate")
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='blog/login.html'), name='login'),
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='blog/logout.html'), name='logout'),
path('signup/', views.signup,name="blog-home"),
path('<str:uid>/<str:token>/', views.activate,name="activate")
```

Attempting to load `127.0.0.1:8000/?uid=Mjg&token=5dj-ddf5e0d6cf0d6f03dfc1` shows the debug page. How to write url config for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because those are query string parameters. You can access them with `request.GET.get('uid')` and `request.GET.get('token')` in your views.

I would put the URL like

`path('', views.activate, name='activate')`

and the view:

```
def activate(request):
    uid = request.GET.get('uid', None)
    token = request.GET.get('token', None)
    # All the other logic
```

And then handle in the view what to do if I have those parameters, etc.

With your current URL (`path('<str:uid>/<str:token>/', views.activate,name="activate")`) what you are expecting is something like: `127.0.0.1/Mjg/5dj-ddf5e0d6`

Comment: I am trying to create a email verification for users after signup. I find the same code anywhere in the internet. Is there any other method to email verification?. When I click the activation mail again and again, it shows the same page "Thanks for your confirmation". is that right?

Comment: Yeah your answer is correct. My program works now. Thankyou